# React native View' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I´am currently getting the following error on the View component inside App.tsx: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component. Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element

I think the issue is related to the library

```
import React from 'react';

import {View,Text,StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native'

import {createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  txt:{
    fontSize: 48
  },
  view: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
})

class screenComponent1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('screenroute2')} title='next page'/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
class screenComponent2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View>
        <Button onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('screenroute1')} title='next page'/>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  screenroute1: screenComponent1,
  screenroute2: screenComponent2,
})


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppNavigator/>
  }
}
```

Comment: 'View' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'View' is not a valid JSX element.
    The types returned by 'render()' are incompatible between these types.
      Type 'React.ReactNode' is not assignable to type

Answer (score 1):

If you're using React native 0.66.3 to 0.70 below version you should this resoulation object in package.json file

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
  },
```